# Issue with Extjs Comboboxes and Google Chrome Canary 74

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, extjs6.5.1

It is not possible to click on the Combobox element, no error on console. I am using Chrome Canary version 74.0.3686.3

It can be reproduced on Extjs site:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.field.ComboBox.html

We have the same issue with events fired by some buttons on our application.

There is additional informations on Sencha forum:
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?471299-Comboboxes-not-working-on-latest-Chrome-Dev

It is working correctly with Google Chrome 72.
Can someone have information on this? I did not find additional information on Chrome site or Extjs site.

Comment: This looks like it is a bug in Chrome or extjs, and should be reported as such to both developers.

Comment: Offtopic, but since sencha's acquisition by idera, I wouldn't use modern. Some of the fired sencha employees said they don't think idera cares about modern at all.

Comment: I sent an issue to Chrome and extjs.

Comment: The issue is resolved in Chrome Version 74.0.3689.0, we have the same problem in Chrome DEV channel Version 73.0.3679.0. Maybe the correction will be merged latter?